# I see a folder and files in Git but they don't show when I clone

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am a git neophyte.

I committed some changes and pushed. I can see the new folder containing the new files in Git web view. This is a pushed change from 39 minutes ago.

The changes I last pushed were refactoring by separating some custom exceptions into separate files and placing them into their own folder.

I cannot see the new folder and contained files in project view in Visual Studio.

I can however see the folder and it's contained files (my changes) in Windows Explorer.

I just want to get back to the latest version of master from 39 minutes ago. I made a backup copy of my solution folder, deleted the folder and tried to clone the repository from Git. That newly cloned repository does not show the changes from 39 minutes ago in Visual Studio solution view but this folder and files do show up in Windows Explorer.

What did I do wrong and how do I get this corrected?

Comment: There's apparently a disconnect between your editor, the local files, and the remote repository. Hard to say what that is from here.

Comment: Visual Studio probably does not update the files from the file system. You have to add new files manually to the project or add a smart directory. Also: Why not add visual studio to your tags?

Comment: @PeterKrebs - I was afraid of that. I have started recreating the changes I made that have been lost. Oh well, at least it goes a lot quicker the second time!

Answer (score 2):

#### VisualStudio pulled a trick on you

As mentioned in the comments, VisualStudio played a trick on you. The Windows Exporer is not lying, the files are there.
The project view in VS does not update files in real time. You add files and directories to the project, but this is not connected to the file system and needs to be updated manually.

If I remember correctly the real directories can be displayed using the Solution Explorer. Switch view and look at the project in Folder View:

[image: Solution Explorer - Switch views]

[image: Solution Explorer - Folder view]

Douple-click the "Folder View" and you should see the real files.

Most developers come to the conclusion that the actual directories and files should be 1:1 with the project and that's reasonable. Lesser motivated people might just put the source code in one directory and create a structure only in Visual Studio. For more chaotic minds you can put all in one directory and forget about it.
I don't think I can fault MicroSoft for this one entirely. Different people want to work differently. They should however make project directories synced with the file system by default at some point.