# Changes made to my c++ project via windows explorer don't show up in my code editor

Tags: c++, unreal

I am working on a project for a game in unreal engine using visual studio 2022 as c++ code editor. I didn't like the structure of the project files, so I went ahead and reorganized them. The problem is, that my editor (I also tried jetbrains rider) doesn't update the solution explorer and rebuilding doesn't work, because the files can't be found. Also I am very new to c++.

I tried - as mentioned - using a different editor as well as update my visual studio version and restarting my pc.

Comment: It's your project file that must be updated. I don't use Visual Studio but you must have a project file, in which the sources (and the corresponding hierarchy) are defined, you probably need to update this file to match what you rearranged.

Comment: ***The problem is, that my editor (I also tried jetbrains rider) doesn't update the solution explorer and rebuilding doesn't work, because the files can't be found. Also I am very new to c++.*** No editor should do that. You will have to manually fix your project files or better yet put them back to the order they were in when you got them. I say better yet because in the future having them reorganized will cause you the same problem when the upstream project has an update or fix you want to apply to your code.

Comment: I wrote this answer a while back, to show the real files in your project explorer: [The project view in VS does not update files in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70016900/10441671). Maybe that helps.

Comment: FYI: The solution file is generated by Unreal's build tool, so changing the file/folder structure is bound to only cause issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

VS Studio by default will save the project properties when first compiled. When you change the folder structure of the project files then you will need to include them again in your project from which ever folder you moved them into. You can also **edit the properties to permanently include subdirectories** to your project. So that in case if you ever move them again they'll still be there.